# How to merge two data frames together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two data frames:

1. *Pre_data_inputs* with the size of (4760,2)
2. *Diff_course_Precourse* with size of (4760,1).

I want to merge these two data frames together  with name *data_inputs*. This new data frame should be (4760,3). I have this code so far:

```
data_inputs = pd.concat([pre_data_inputs, Diff_Course_PreCourse], axis=1)
```

But the size of *data_inputs* now is (4950,3).
I don't know what is the problem. I would be appreciated if anybody can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do indices match between both dataframes as you are assuming here with `concat`? Otherwise use `merge` to merge on a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your index matches in both cases you can go with:

```
pre_data_inputs.merge(Diff_Course_PreCourse, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Otherwise you might want to `reset_index()` on both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Parfait commented, the index of your data frames has to match for `concat` to work as you describe it.

For example:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape = (3,1)))
     0
0  0.0
1  0.0
2  0.0

d2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape = (3,2)), index = range(2,5))
     0    1
2  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0
```

Since the index doesn't match the result data frame will have a number of rows equal to the unique index set (0,1,2,3,4)

```
pd.concat([d1, d2], axis = 1)
     0    0    1
0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  NaN  1.0  1.0
4  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

You could use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before the *concat* or force one of the data frames to use the index of the other

```
pd.concat([d1, d2.set_index(d1.index)], axis = 1)
     0    0    1
0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  1.0  1.0
```